# “Unexpected ORM Query Translation: CAST and Unnest Functions in Django”

Tags: postgresql, django-orm, django-filter, unnest, django-annotate

I'm trying to execute a query using Django ORM to obtain the following SQL query:

```
python: 3.9.16
django: 3.2.19
value = text[]
```

```
SELECT CAST(x AS float)
FROM public.collection_basic_arrays
CROSS JOIN unnest(value) AS t(x)
WHERE x::float BETWEEN 0.001 AND 0.01
```

However, the ORM is translating it to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT CAST(unnest("collection_basic_arrays"."value") AS double precision) AS "value_unnest" 
FROM "collection_basic_arrays" 
WHERE 
(CAST(unnest("collection_basic_arrays"."value") AS double precision) > 0.001 
 AND CAST(unnest("collection_basic_arrays"."value") AS double precision) <= 0.01)


ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 5:  AND CAST(unnest("collection_basic_arrays"."value") AS doubl...
                  ^ 

SQL state: 0A000
Character: 219
```

I'm using a custom function and Django built-in functions to execute the query. I'm trying to obtain the query result with the following function:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Func, Q

class Unnest(Func):
    function = 'unnest'

def execute(self):
    value_key = 'value'
    annotate = {}
    filter = {}
    annotate[value_key + '_unnest'] = Unnest(value_key)
    value_key += '_unnest'

    if value_key in annotate:
        conversion = Cast(annotate[value_key], models.FloatField())
        if conversion is not None:
            annotate[value_key] = conversion

    else:
        conversion = Cast(value_key, models.FloatField())
        if conversion is not None:
            annotate[value_key] = conversion
            value_key += '_conv'

    filter[value_key + '__gt'] = 0.001
    filter[value_key + '__lte'] = 0.01
    data = MyModel.objects.annotate(**annotate).filter(Q(**filter)).values(value_key)

    query_str = str(data.query)

    return data
```

Is there any way to obtain the expected SQL query using Django ORM? I'd appreciate any suggestions or solutions you may have.

Thank you very much.